# Why doesn't my function call referring to the base of my prototype chain work?

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

Hoping my question was clear I have the following code:

```
function Pane(){
}
Pane.prototype.testo = function (){
  console.log("I'm a function");
}

TileBased.prototype = new Pane();
function TileBased(){
}
TileBased.prototype.test = function (){
  console.log("I'm a function");
}

Level.prototype = new TileBased();
function Level(){
  console.log(this instanceof Pane); // -> true
  this.test();
  this.testo();
}

testLevel = new Level();
```

Here, this.test prints `I'm a function` alright but this.testo throws: `this.testo is not a function`

Edit:
Turns out I watered it down too much and was considering too little of my code. The code here works. On the full version of my program, I had made an array called level and also assigned `new Level` to a variable called level. I found out, after searching "level" through my project's directory that I had conflicting variable names.

Comment: I just pasted the above code into jsfiddle and the result is true, I'm a function, I'm a function. Not seeing an error.

Comment: For the record, I cannot reproduce your error in console, and the prototype chain seems ok, by inspecting the objects

Comment: It's my first time using a prototype chain so I thought I did something wrong... but the problem was elsewhere as Lewis made me realize... I simply had conflicting variable names. Sorry about that..

Comment: I'll delete in a few minutes.

Comment: @DominicGrenier You don't have to delete a question just because you had made a mistake. That's the whole point of asking here. You can add your solution or explain what you did wrong in your question post

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the methods that Tilebased inherits from Pane since you're redefining it after declaring the prototype;

***UPDATED TO INCLUDE WORKING AND NON-WORKING CODEPENS***

View this codepen that reproduces the error: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaWGpW

You need to move

```
function TileBased(){
}
```

Before the first instance of Tilebased;

```
TileBased.prototype = new Pane();
```

Try this;

```
function Pane(){
}
Pane.prototype.testo = function (){
  console.log("I'm a function");
}

function TileBased(){
}
TileBased.prototype = new Pane();
TileBased.prototype.test = function (){
  console.log("I'm a function");
}

Level.prototype = new TileBased();
function Level(){
  console.log(this instanceof Pane); // -> true
  this.test();
  this.testo();
}

testLevel = new Level();
```

Working codepen with the lines swapped: view here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgJERB

Comment: Function definitions are hoisted, so it should not matter where he is defining the function, the interpreter moves it to the top anyway

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis It's not about where it's defined, more so that he defines the prototype for Tilebased like this, `tilebased.prototype = ...` then immediately overrides it on the next line, i.e., `Tilebased = function(){}`

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere as even your suggestion doesn't work. I'll have a look around and let you know.

Comment: Mentally running the code doesn't strike me as it having an error and I am not experiencing his problem in the console either

Comment: @DominicGrenier Yeah, that's pretty weird. It works fine in the codepen but I had the same error you did initially, that the function wasn't defined.

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis Wouldn't `function Tilebased(){}` set it to be a blank function, clearing any prototype definitions?

Comment: @Lewis and I am telling you that this does not matter :) The interpreter will take the function definition and move it on top, so when the code is actually executed it's like this: `function Tilebased()` and then `Tilebased.prototype = ...` EDIT: [about hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)